# How do I fix this uncaught exception error

Tags: ios, syntax

I am not even sure how to search for this one I created a IBOutlet in storyboard and did the control drag to create the linking and gave it a variable name. There lies the problem I mistyped the variable named so i went in to the corresponding .h file and deleted the entry went back into storyboard and did the drag  to the .h file and re-created the variable and the link this time I typed the variable name correctly. Now I get this uncaught exception error setValue:for undefined key( and it shows the misspelled variable I deleted.

I have since redeleted the good variable
ran a clean  from the tools menu
closed the project and reopened it

if I do not have any variable I get the error and it points to what was the good variable name if I have the good variable loaded then I get the error pointing to the bad variable name.

ARRARAGGGHH

Things like this have happened before and I think it has something to do with XCode itself but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Currently I am running the the latest version of Xcode and my app project is based mainly on iOS6 if that helps any

the variables in question are

detailGraphic    <---good
detailGrpahic    <---bad

here is the message I see in the log when I have the good variable in place

```
013-06-02 11:42:22.146 IMOB[35446:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DetailViewController 0x1cdcfe80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key detailGrpahic.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x326352a3 0x3a35d97f 0x32634f99 0x32ea21d9 0x32e9df2b 0x325bb61b 0x345da31d 0x345d9b9b 0x344d203d 0x3445c46d 0x344b114b 0x344b1091 0x344b0f75 0x344b0e99 0x344b05d9 0x344b04c1 0x3449eb93 0x2991c33 0x3449e833 0x344ff25d 0x34581f81 0x32f43277 0x3260a5df 0x3260a291 0x32608f01 0x3257bebd 0x3257bd49 0x361542eb 0x34491301 0xb3cdd 0x3a794b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

here is the message I see in the log when I do not have either variable

```
2013-06-02 12:13:07.640 IMOB[35503:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DetailViewController 0x1dd78dc0>  setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key detailGraphic.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x326352a3 0x3a35d97f 0x32634f99 0x32ea21d9 0x32e9df2b 0x325bb61b 0x345da31d 0x345d9b9b 0x344d203d 0x3445c46d 0x344b114b 0x344b1091 0x344b0f75 0x344b0e99 0x344b05d9 0x344b04c1 0x3449eb93 0x2974c33 0x3449e833 0x344ff25d 0x34581f81 0x32f43277 0x3260a5df 0x3260a291 0x32608f01 0x3257bebd 0x3257bd49 0x361542eb 0x34491301 0x94da5 0x3a794b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and running it again?

Comment: yes cleaned and closed and restarted no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Connections Inspector `(Cmd + option + 6)` for this element in your Storyboard. You will see that it is connected (Referencing Outlets) to something that doesn't exist anymore. Undo that connection (click on the X for it) and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much I was under the mis-impression that if you deleted the variable the link would go away as well. Thanks again for the correction